# How to use https in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

when I use https in play framework it shows like this

WARN  akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(play-dev-mode) Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': Unsupported HTTP method: The HTTP method started with 0x16 rather than any known HTTP method from 127.0.0.1:45436. Perhaps this was an HTTPS request sent to an HTTP endpoint?

if anyone know how to use HTTPS in play framework,please explain the steps properly.
i can't clearly understad the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ConfiguringHttps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of "sbt run" we need to use  "sbt run -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttp.port=disabled"
and it runs in port number :9443

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).